# Google play search algorithm

Tags: android, search, google-play

I'm a new android app developer and I just published my first app 3 days ago.

When I search for my app with one more of the words that are in the title (of the app) I can barely find my app in the list!

Yes, I searched for this a lot over the Internet and I saw in other places people talking about the search algorithm decides by downloads, rating and +1s. I have the best rating, a lot of reviews, okay amount of downloads and I see apps with no downloads, no rating, small description, show up above me in the list.

So my questions are: Am I missing something here? Why is my app so low in the list? Does the search update every week or so?

Answer (score 0):

hey use this link to find app only put app package name here

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename&hl=en
```

only replace packagename to your app package name

then you find app

or search by Developer name....